# datagridview values disappear after i close the form

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, datagridview

im having problems with my datagrids i used this code to copy selected rows from datagrid1 into datagrid2.. my data grid is connected to a table in a database..

```
for (int i = 0; i < datagrid1.SelectedRows.Count; i++){
    int index = datagrid2.Rows.Add();
    datagrid2.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = datagrid1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    datagrid2.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = datagrid1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
}
```

its working fine and adding the selected values to datagrid2..  but the problem is when i close the form and run it again.. the datagrid2 clears all its values..

is there any way that i can keep the values inside the datagrid2 and only clear it when i press a button? thankss

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to keep the values, one of them would be the following:

When you need your form to disappear from screen, you don't close it but only hide for example like that (supposed it is not main form of your application):

```
// Using FormClosing event
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   // as example, exitingApp (bool) should be your global flag to distinguish 
   // if you want to hide this form only or you close your application completely
   if (!exitingApp) 
   {
     e.Cancel = true;
     Hide();
   }
}
```

Take into account that you should keep somewhere the reference to this form to be able to show it again like that:

```
if (form2 == null)
{
   form2 = new Form2();
} 
form2.Show();
```

Another way would be to store content of your form somewhere else before closing it and restore when the form is loaded again, but I personally would prefer the first way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static class that has static list and you store the data of the gridview in it. and load the gridview of the list data on page_load.

as the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Global
/// </summary>
public static class Global
{

    public static List<GridView> GridViewList = new List<GridView>();

}
```